# Show duplicates from one list with different ID's using linq

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks, entity

I have a table with

```
ID  Name  ExcelID

1   a     1

2   b     1

3   a     2

4   b     2

5   c     2
```

I need to show the duplicates between two of the Excel ID's, so the output should show me 'C' as that is the unique value between excelid 1 & 2. For this reason i used the queries below to compare the two sets of data.

```
var assets = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
            .Where(c => c.FORATExcelId == fptexcel)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();


var assetsold = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
            .Where(c => c.FORATExcelId == fptexcelprevious)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I have grouped the data into two lists, one being excel id 1 and the second query being 2.

However if i try to use the except method to show the distinct values, it just shows me all values from both lists

Comment: you're question is very unclear... why is C unique? where are the two lists?

Comment: C is the only value that appears in ExcelId 2 but not in 1. The two lists are comprised from the assets and assetsold queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for names where you only get one result :

```
var uniqueResult = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
        .Where(c => c.FORATExcelId == fptexcel || c.FORATExcelId == fptexcelprevious)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Where(c => c.Count() == 1)
        .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: If I wanted to show values that have been either added or deleted, would i need to add another where clause to check if the excelid matches the previous excelid?

Comment: What does it means when excelid = previousexcelid ? I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueItems = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
   .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
   .Where(p => p.Count() == 1)
   .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault());
```

should do the trick?

Trying it on the list you gave, it returned neatly item (5, "c", 2)

Comment: Thanks, just have one more question.. how might i go about only showing the duplicates for names in excelid 4 and 8 for example?